# How to reopen Simulator keyboard in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode

In Xcode 6 my Simulator keyboard is hidden. I don't know how but I need to reopen it. I don't know how can I do this.

My problem is when I click on text field my simulator keyboard does not open  and I haven't any idea how to reopen this again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing your application (by using KIF, for example) you need to disable Hardware Keyboard in **Hardware** menu (iOS Simulator).
[image]

In another way, select **Connect Hardware Keyboard** and then press **Toggle Software Keyboard**.

Answer (score 0):

check this:

Open Simulator.

Go to Hardware.

Then select Keyboard.

Then choose iOS Users Same Layout As OS X

Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> iOS Users Same Layout As OS X

it's working :)